# What's the link between "Due Date" and "Planes, Trains & Automobiles"?

Tags: due-date, planes-trains-and-automobiles

I know that their plots only resemble each other but they also have a few similar scenes. Was this resemblance only in the degree of an homage or did the director, producer, writers or any other people had some kind of a goal to make a version of [*Planes, Trains & Automobiles* (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093748/) on their mind when they were planning for [*Due Date* (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1231583/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Todd Phillips, the director of *Due Date* has stated that he grew up on John Hughes (writer and director of *Planes, Trains and Automobiles*) [movies](http://variety.com/2003/film/news/hughes-wields-a-big-club-in-new-h-wood-1117880968/):

> “I’d like to say I grew up on Preston Sturges,” says “Old School”
>   director Todd Phillips. “But I truly grew up on Ivan Reitman and John
>   Hughes.

Phillips also expresses his love for *Planes, Trains and Automobiles*:

> Hughes’ 1987 Steve Martin-John Candy comedy, “Planes, Trains and
>   Automobiles,” Phillips says, “is one of the greatest comedies of all
>   time.”

The fact that Todd Phillips has stated that *Planes, Trains and Automobiles* is one of the greatest comedies of all time is an obvious reason for wanting to pay homage to the movie.